# Damaged OLED LCD voltage regulator replacement

Tags: arduino, voltage-regulator, lcd

I have a 128*32 OLED LCD that is used with an Arduino. I recently damaged the voltage regulator and was hoping to be able to repair the board by soldering off the damaged component and replacing it with a new component. What should I replace it with? The datasheet can be found here: https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/0.91inch_OLED_Module
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest to just replace it with the component you removed unless there's something else that makes more sense based on how you damaged it?

Schematic calls out a [XC6206P332MR-G](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Torex-Semiconductor/XC6206P332MR-G?qs=AsjdqWjXhJ%2FXxNpRY3zZ8g%3D%3D) which outputs 3.3V based on a ~5V input. Were you trying to use this with a 12V supply when you broke it?

If you have another good source of 3.3V somewhere in your project you might not even need the voltage regulator so you'd just desolder and pump in 3.3V from that 3.3V supply to the desoldered pin where you need it.

Comment: Many thanks. I think it was damaged because I created a voltage spike from removing and replacing the power module that I usually use. Will try feeding 3v3 directly.

Comment: I've decided to abandon it and use another screen, but thanks anyway.